# ¿Hay algun error en mi código conforme lo que pedía?

Tags: python, division

```
def operacio(num1,num2): #recibe los dos valores
    division = num1 / num2 #realiza la op
    return division #envia op
    
def main():
    try:
        numero1 = int(input("Introduce el primer numero (solo numero): ")) 

        numero2 = int(input("Introduece el segundo número (solo numero): "))
        
        resultado = operacio(numero1,numero2) #envio els dos valors
        print(f"\nEl resultado de la operación es {resultado}")
        
    except ZeroDivisionError: #manejo el fallo
        print("NO se puede dividir per 0!!")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Buenas señores y gracias ante todo, quería pedir si mi codigo cumple con lo pedido en el ejercicio del examen:

"Realiza un script que pide dos numeros y los divida entre sí y a continuación muestre el resultado, utiliza "ZeroDivisionError" para manejar el fallo"

Espero respuestas, gracias

Comment: ¿Lo probaste tú mismo?

Comment: Si, pero no veo ningún fallo

Comment: Puedes hacer la división directamente en `main()`. Estrictamente hablando, puedes obviar el `if __name__` y el `def main()`, dejando sólo el cuerpo de la función.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Dice literalmente "dos números" ¿podemos asumir que son números enteros y no reales? Porque haces un casting a `int`... ¿Podemos asumir que el usuario no ingresara algo inválido, algo que no represente un numero? De la segunda no dice nada el enunciado, pero de la primera pregunta... yo al menos no asumiría que son enteros...

Comment: he estado mirando tu código y si, parece que no hay ningún error. Un truco en la programación es mantener todo ordenado así que te vendría mejor llamarlo "operacion" y no "operacio" así te acostumbras porque al tener mucho código te confundirás.

Comment: Coincido en lo que te indica @FJSevilla, deberías cambiar el cast de `int` a `float` para que admita tanto números  enteros como reales. Por lo demás el programa está correcto.